Stability analysis - 0 dB crossover point
I have a question about Bode diagrams. For example if a Bode plot (gain) cross 2 time the 0 dB axis which point should we consider. Should we analyse both of them and keep them stable (good phase and gain margin), if we can not play anywhere else to have only one intersection point?

Gain margin is irrelevant when the gain is 0 dB. What is the relevance of the term  node diagram? A bode plot isn't a node diagram (unless they've changed the definition recently).

When the 0dB-axis is crossed twice, you must use the full Nyquist criterion for stability analyses. This can be done in the s-plane (loop gain) or also in form of a Bode diagram (but not the simplified one).

@Andyaka , I mean bode diagram (it was a typo) ….yes I said gain margin just to precise the whole stability criteria. But at the crossover frequency we don’t check the gain margin

@LvW I got your point
